# angular 2 + MDL blank pages

Tags: angular, material-design-lite, angular2-mdl

I'm trying to develop a web app with Angular 2 and Material Design Lite.

But all the html pages comming from binded components and using MDL are not displayed.

After hours of searches on the internet, I found out that it is quite a common problem and many people say that it is better not to use MDL with angular 2.

Did anyone manage to make these two frameworks work together ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's easy. Just use angular2-mdl. See the demo app http://mseemann.io/angular2-mdl/ or the corresponding github project: https://github.com/mseemann/angular2-mdl. If you want to play around there is a plnkr link in the github project.

[image]

Comment: I already tried it but it returned me the following error :
npm ERR! Windows_NT 10.0.10586
npm ERR! argv "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "install" "angular2-mdl" "--save"
npm ERR! node v6.7.0
npm ERR! npm  v3.10.3
npm ERR! code ENOSELF

npm ERR! Refusing to install angular2-mdl as a dependency of itself

npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\MIW\Desktop\test\angular2-mdl\npm-debug.log

Comment: 'Refusing to install angular2-mdl as a dependency of itself ' ?? looks like you are trying to run npm install angular2-mdl in the angular2-mdl folder. why?

Comment: I thought it wasn't properly installed as I can't run ng serve

Comment: are you using angular-cli?

Comment: I'd like to be able to run ng serve while working on my project, yes... I only cloned the git hub repo. I don't get what do to next... :/

Comment: that's the problem. you don't need to clone the github repo.  here is a simple repo: https://github.com/mseemann/a2-mdl-webpack that uses angular2 and angular2-mdl. you can use this as a starting point. clone it, run npm install in it and run ng serve. also you need to install angular-cli globally (https://github.com/angular/angular-cli#installation) to use the ng commands.

Comment: Ok this worked thanks ! But what's the difference between this repo and the previous one ?

Comment: angular2-mdl is the package that provides angualr2 components for material design lite. the a2-mdl-webpack repos is just a demo how to use it.

Answer (score -1):

You know there's a framework called material2 build from the angular-team? :)

Github: https://github.com/angular/material2

Demos: https://material2-test.firebaseapp.com/

Getting started: https://github.com/angular/material2/blob/master/GETTING_STARTED.md

Answer (score -1):

Yes! It's not good to use MDL with angular or angular2 as theres angular-material for angular1.x and material2 for angular2 which have already introduced a lot of components already. However if you really want to use MDL, here I have developed a component library built on top of MDL.

[ng2-mdl: https://github.com/sabbirrahman/ng2-mdl](https://github.com/sabbirrahman/ng2-mdl)

It works fine with angular 2 final and angular-cli. Though I haven't added AOT support yet!

Comment: Angular2-mdl (https://github.com/mseemann/angular2-mdl) is perfectly fine. It's far progressed, stable and has a growing user base.